# HTML sanitizer version getting error in server build

Tags: c#, html, .net, html-sanitizing, sanitizer

I have installed a package of HTML sanitizer in my local(v7.0.0). it works fine in my local. So I built the code and deployed to server. But in the server the sanitizer page gets encountered with error wherever I have put sanitizer methods in the code

I am expecting that the sanitizer method gets cleared successfully and the input fields doesn't allow cross scripting

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Got the resolution for the issue. it was due to the version mismatch between the server and my local.

Answer (score 0):

Got the issue that was bugging. The issue was due to the **version mismatch** between the server and my local. Now it's sorted out.